# How to Access existing realmDB of clientApp in KotlinMultiPlatform Module

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to build common data parsing module in KMM where I need to save the data in the same realm DB which is already present in the client's Android App or iOS app?
I would like to know if this is feasible or can we access this in the client and KMM Module both?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access platform dependent code from kotlin multiplatform common area.
But the inverse is true.
Check out [Hexagonal Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software))

In Kotlin common sources, have at least these classes below. Change the class and method names according to your need.

```kotlin
// kotlin common

interface PlatformWrapper {
    fun save(some: DataX)
    // ... other methods
}

// Database will never know anything about Realm, Room, Sqlite ...
// Database will work only with PlatformWrapper
class Database(private val db: PlatformWrapper) {
    fun saveWork() {
            // some code
            db.save(...)
    }
}
```

In android code source, you have to wrap the realm database.

```kotlin
class AndroidRealmWrapper(
    private val realm : RealmDb...
) : PlatformWrapper {
    override fun save(something: DataX) {
        // convert the data for realm
        realm.save(somethingConverted)
    }
}
```

Use them from the platform's application code.

```
val realmDb = ... // android implementation of realm

val realmWrapper = AndroidRealmWrapper(realm)
val db = Database(realmWrapper)

// Use only Database class
db.saveWork(...)

// You can change the database wrapper in future.
// i.e. If you decide to use any other db
```

IOS implementation would be like android implementation.

Hope, it helps.